# Rollback does not rollback to the correct revision

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, rollbacks

I want to rollback a question because someone who is not the questioner randomly picked out one language tag when the OP selected 4. Since there is no mention of what language the OP is using (and there are 4 answers) because he claims that is 
a "general question", I wanted to rollback that edit. The question language is completely valid in two of the removed tags.
When I did so, I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49395797/revisions):

> Rollback to Revision 3

When the tags where removed in Revision 4.

Is this due to the Revision 4 having "Improved Edit" so they are taken as 1 revision?

As an extra question, would rolling back be the appropriate action here?

I know that further information was added by the questioner in Revision 5, what I normally do is rollback to the desired revision and add the OP's last edit in (when it makes sense).

Comment: Don't know what happened with the tags but there was new information added by OP in revision 5, why did you roll that back?

Comment: @Oleg The idea was to rollback and add back the information, but since the rollback "failed", didn't want to edit further